# MapReduce read input from Redis

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, redis

I want to write a Java Program which does the MapReduce Job(e.g. word count). The input is from the Redis. How can I write the Map Class to retrieve one by one from the Redis and do some process in the Map class, like I did before which read from HDFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no OOTB feature that allows us to do that. But you might find things like [Jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis) helpful. Jedis is a Java client using which you can read/write data to/from Redis. See [this](http://blog.gopivotal.com/products/making-hadoop-mapreduce-work-with-a-redis-cluster) for an example.

If you are not strongly coupled to Java, you might also find [R3](http://heynemann.github.io/r3/) useful. R3 is a map reduce engine written in python using a Redis backend.

HTH

Comment: hmm...it looks so complicate. Is there a way that simply read a set from the Redis(use Jedis) and parse to the Mapper Class as the value?

Comment: Not in my knowledge. You can probably wait for some more time for experts to comment as i'm not much into Redis stuff.

Comment: [Redisson](https://redisson.org) easily allows to run Map Reduce over Redis data.

Answer (score 1):

obviously,you need to customize your InputFormat.
Please read [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#inputformat) tutorial to learn how to write your own custom InputFormat and RecordReader.

Answer (score 0):

Put your keys in HDFS. In map(), just query from redis based on input key.

Comment: Doing that would lose the advantage of having your data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Redisson](https://redisson.org) it's a Redis based In-Memory Data Grid for Java. It allows to execute Map Reduce over data stored in Redis.

More documentation [here](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/9.-distributed-services#95-distributed-mapreduce-service).